# iteration of mysql query using for each in php

Tags: php

For example the value of array is:

```
Array ( [0] => what [1] => is [2] => life [3] => )
```

This value is stored in a variable called `$specialized`

```
$string = "SELECT * FROM questions where";        
$intA = 0;
foreach ($specailized as $spec) {
    $string += " question like '%" + $spec +"'% ";  
    if ($intA > 1) { 
        $str += " and ";
    }
    $intA++;
}
print($string);
```

The result is always numbers. Like 001
if this possible?
 I want to get a string value stored in $string like this.

```
SELECT * FROM questions where question like '% what%' and question like '% is%' and question like '%life%'
```

Comment: Using `+`'s is a JS/C method of concatenation. In PHP, you're to use dots `.`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this

```
$string = "SELECT * FROM questions where 1=1 ";        
$specailized = array("what","is","life");
foreach ($specailized as $spec) {
    $string .= " and question like '%" . $spec ."%' ";  
}

echo $string;
```

Also note, that if array values comes from user, then you should care about sql injections

Comment: yup it is not working when i user $string variable mysqli query

Comment: but thanks it works

Comment: the error is the single qoute is misplaced

Comment: Yep, correct, I edited

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.